# How to get path of directory which is in SD Card?

Tags: android, storage, android-storage

I want to create directory in SD card same as in the internal storage.

My internal storage path is `"sdcard/<my_directory_name>/"`

I want to create the same directory in root of SD card.

I have try the following ways to find the path of directory.

1. `sdcard1/<my_directory_name>/`
2. `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +"/<my_directory_name>/"`

Please suggest the way to find SD card path.

Comment: `My internal storage path is "sdcard/<my_directory_name>/"`. Two times impossible. You mean `My external storage path is "/sdcard/<my_directory_name>/"`

Answer (score 2):

You do not have arbitrary access to [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+. Hence, there is no useful path, from a filesystem standpoint. You are welcome to use `getExternalFilesDirs()` and kin -- if they return 2+ locations, the second and subsequent ones are on removable storage, and you can read and write to those locations.

Comment: It Gives only one record "/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/"

Comment: @Naitik: `/storage/sdcard0/` would seem to fit the typical removable storage naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Although as CommonsWare answered, you cannot read or write in Secondary External Storage, here's a way to generate it's path.

```
System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"); //returns /storage/extSdCard
```

You can also use `String path = "/storage/extSdCard";` but again you cannot write files there.

Edit: As @CommonsWare commented, there is no guarantee of this method. Though when I tested it, it worked, but again, if he says there's no guarantee, you can take his word.

Comment: There is no guarantee that this environment variable will be set to any meaningful value.